# BouncyCastle JCE Provider not Recognized after installation

Tags: java

I am configuring BouncyCastle provider in my JRE with the following steps:

1. Added the jar file **bcprov-jdk16-146** to my /jre/lib/ext folder.
2. In jre/lib/security/java.security file I have appended my JCE provider as

```
security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

3. I restarted my server and executed the keytool command as:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myproject -keystore C:/myproject.keystore -storepass myproject -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

4. It throws: **keytool error (likely untranslated): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider**

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Use version 1.46 from maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46

Comment: I have used the same. 1.46